# Как привязать к одной кнопке две разных функции?(Python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создавал простую кнопку с помощью модуля tkinter на Python. Всегда привязывал выполнение функции к кнопке при ее нажатии с помощью аргумента **command**:

```
button = Button(root,
                text = 'Print',
                command = func_1)
```

Но теперь мне нужно выполнить при нажатии две функции подряд. Я пробовал так:

```
button = Button(root,
                text = 'Print',
                command = func_1 and func_2)
```

Но ничего не вышло. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне это сделать?

Comment: `command=lambda: (func_1(), func_2())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого Вам нужна функция, которая не принимает аргументы и будет вызывать множество функций, которые Вы хотите. Например:

```py
def call_funcs():
    func_1()
    func_2()
```

Затем эту функцию передать как параметр `command`:

```py
button = Button(root,
                text = 'Print',
                command = call_funcs)
```

---

Или же можно воспользоваться безымянной `lambda`-функцией:

```py
button = Button(root,
                text = 'Print',
                command = lambda: (func_1(), func_2()))
```

Но использовать так `lambda`-функции это не очень правильно, т.к. они должны что-то возвращать (в данном случае она возвращает кортеж из результатов выполнения `func_1` и `func_2`). Но это сработает.